# Ubuntu 14.04 - Slow Boot

Tags: ubuntu, boot, acpi

I have an ubuntu 14.04 server, the server will be in a parking to manage it with a software.

When I turn ON `ACPI`, my server took more than 2minutes to boot, else it takes only 30-40secondes.

I need to have `ACPI` ON because when I push the power button it needs to send the request to shut down and not directly cut the power (as far I know it's ACPI who manage the power button).

To conclude, my server needs to have a boot time more acceptable and with the power button working.

You can find boot log: [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/RH0Kn0JD*)

And bootchar log: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMutw.jpg)

I'm not able to read properly these logs, thank for help!

Comment: It's taking over a minute to mount the hard disk. Maybe the system is not shutting down cleanly and has to do a disk scan

Comment: I reboot the server with, sudo reboot. Do it's wrong ?

Comment: that should be ok if you wait till the disk is unmounted before turning off the power

Comment: Yes, I didn't cut the power. The strange thing is if I disable ACPI, my system will boot in 30-40 seconds

Comment: @GuillaumeBrulet Since you do "sudo reboot" check out various reboot options : http://michalorman.com/2013/10/fix-ubuntu-freeze-during-restart/

Comment: also, try toggling UEFI/Legacy options in BIOS.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I don't have access anymore to the server for the moment. I'll try as fast I can and keep you informed.